# Download and save a File in JDeveloper - iOS particularly

Tags: java, ios, download, storage, jdeveloper

I am developing a simple iOS native application, using the Oracle's `JDeveloper`.

How may I download a file, by giving an URL, and store it in the iOS device?
For example, in Android the code to access the Storage is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and to download a file, I can use a `HttpURLConnection` and set the `requestMode` to `GET`.

Once the `JDeveloper` allows to deploy apps to Android an iOS devices, how do I perform such calls? What are the java classes that allow me to download and store a file? I didn't find any information in Oracle's documentation.

Comment: hello, in iOS you don't develop in java, you uses Objective-c

Comment: Yes, but JDeveloper allows programmers to develop iOS and Android native apps using Java.. I know that by default obj-c is used.. If you aren't familiarized check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/setup.htm

Comment: then you are not developing a native app.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how to download and store a file using Jdeveloper?